# Möbius transform which fixes real/imaginary axes must also transform $|z| = R_1$ to $|z| = R_2$ for $R_1,R_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Suppose there exists $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, \quad a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$ such that if $z_0=K \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f(z_0)\in \mathbb{R}$ AND if $z_0 = L \in i\mathbb{R}$ then $f(z_0) \in i\mathbb{R}$

Prove that such a Möbius transform also maps circles centred at the origin to another circle centred at the origin (not necessarily of the same radius).

I have tried to tackle this by working backwards, showing that a Möbius transform which maps a circle of radius $R_1$ to a circle of radius $R_2$, will also for some $a,b,c,d$ also fix the imaginary and real axes, but I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: There are various ways to tackle this problem. One approach is to note that the image of such a circle meets the real axis at two points and also meets the imaginary axis at tow points.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, the circle meets the axes at the points $r,-r,ri,-ri$ where $r \in \mathbb{R}$ is the radius of the circle. I suppose I have to show that this Mobius transform which fixes the axes scales all these points by a constant factor? $Kz$ is a Mobius transform with $a=K,b=0,c=0,d=1$, and clearly maps points on the axes to points on the same axes, and also transforms an origin-centred circle of radius $r$ to one of radius $Kr$, but how to show that this is the only Mobius transform which fixes the axes? There could be others surely?

Comment: What I mean is that the *image circle* meets the real axis at two points and the imaginary axis at  two points. That should only be possible if the center is at the origin.